# Why is my value of a javascript object undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I keep getting undefined when I attempt to output the objects value via chrome console.  Code:

```
ws.on('message', function(message) {
     var JSONobj = {"cmd":"updatesb","name":"TestName"};
     console.log('JSON Name Value: %s', message.name); //<--does not work
     console.log('JSON Name Value: %s', JSONobj.name); //<----WORKS!!!!
});
```

The message argument in ws.on passes {"cmd":"updatesb","name":"TestName"} via websocket communication. The first console output is undefined.  The second output is TestName. Why is message.name  undefined when it should have a value of TestName and how do I get the value from message.name?

Comment: What's `console.log(message)` ?

Comment: Are you sure message isn't a string? if you console.log(message) what do you get? If it is a string you can convert it to an object with: `var JSONobj = JSON.parse(message);`

Comment: @HMR message is a string.  JSON.parse(message); worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like your `message` parameter is a string, not an object.

You can parse that string as JSON by calling `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: message is a string and not an object, which is why I was receiving undefined.  JSON,parse(); worked.  Thank you SLaks.

Comment: You could confirm this by using `console.log(typeof(message))` FYI

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 message.name = 'xxx';
 console.log('JSON Name Value: %s', message.name);
```

to see if the `message.name` succeeds. As others pointed out, `message` is most likely not what you think.

Try also `console.log(message);` and examine the output.

Also, it may be that the `on` handler receives more then just the message so the handler should in fact look like `function(something_else, message)`, but it is hard to know without knowing what ws is.